# How do you work with sub forms in Laravel 4

Tags: php, validation, symfony, laravel

I'm trying to find the way laravel 4 works with array data in requests but can't find any example, tutorials, documentation about it on the net.

Example:

```
<select name="productDetails[0][service]">...</select>
<select name="productDetails[0][product]">...</select>
<select name="productDetails[0][action]">...</select>
<select name="productDetails[1][service]">...</select>
<select name="productDetails[1][product]">...</select>
<select name="productDetails[1][action]">...</select>
```

Ends up being:

```
$_GET['productDetails'][0]['service']
$_GET['productDetails'][0]['product']
$_GET['productDetails'][0]['action']
$_GET['productDetails'][1]['service']
$_GET['productDetails'][1]['product']
$_GET['productDetails'][1]['action']
```

Now if i want to make my form work correctly i have the read this data, but i can't assume that productDetails is an array and features 0. I want to use the facilities provided by Laravel/Symfony's HTTP Foundation components.

I tried without avail:

```
Request::get('productDetails.0.service', null); //Doesn't work
Request::get('productDetails[0][service]', null); //Doesn't work
Request::get('productDetails.1.service', null); //Doesn't work
Request::get('productDetails[1][service]', null); //Doesn't work
```

I thought these versions would work because you can access session, config and probably many other data sources like this. Just stumped that this doesn't work... On the other hand, this following snippet works, but it's ugly cause you can't assume productDetails is an array at all times, you also can't assume 0 index exists nor "service" index too...

```
Request::get('productDetails', array())[0]['service']; //Works but ugly
Request::get('productDetails', array())[1]['service']; //Works but ugly
```

So what is the right way to accomplish this?

---

**Edit #1**

Added symfony to the tags, and i realize now that the Request object from Laravel really is an HTTPFoundation from symfony, so how do these guys work with all this? Am i the only one? I'm sure it's just a matter of naming conventions, i might not be using the right terms to search my documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhhhh finaly found it:

```
Request::query('productDetails[0]', array()); //array('service' => 2, 'product' => null, 'action' => null);
Request::query('productDetails[1]', array()); //array('service' => 3, 'product' => null, 'action' => null);
Request::query('productDetails[0][service]', array()); //2
Request::query('productDetails[1][service]', array()); //3
```

Had to dig a little in the Request class and Symfony HTTPFoundation but was able to find examples and codes down there that explained how it worked.

Hope this helps others...

Comment: Finaly, had to also create "Request" method in the Illuminate\Http\Request to allow access to the HTTPFoundation Request variables since the GET mecanism doesn't apply the same way QUERY does. Creating a pull request on Laravel to apply this to all as it is a great addition

Answer (score 0):

Any reason not to switch them to be separate inputs?

```
<select name="productDetailService">...</select>
<select name="productDetailsProduct">...</select>
<select name="productDetailsAction">...</select>
```

As I'm sure you realize, that would mean processing each one in separately in your form processing code.

However, if you aren't trying to make a form where you need to add new `productDetails` fields ad-hoc, I don't see a reason to make the code more confusing by using arrays in that way - processing each one separately or treating them as separate fields (vs an aggregate within an array) might be the better way to go.

Comment: Obviously it's because i plan on having more than one productDetail... I could use a "productDetails_0_service", "productDetails_1_service" naming convention, but it goes against good programing practices IMO. I prefer by far having arrays and just validating the structure of each, but i just don't want to be stuck with having to do it all if it already exists...

Comment: Just saw that Request is in fact an HTTPFoundation Request, trying to look at how they handle subforms in symfony, it might be the key to my question